# ModelState.AddModelError not showing the error message sent

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

I am trying to show error messages for inputs using ModelState.AddModelError.  However, the error messages will not show on the view. Below are my codes:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Connection(Login login)
{
    if (!(ModelState.IsValid))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Veuillez entrer un nom utilisateur");
        ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Veuillez entrer un mot de passe");
        return View("LoginPage", login);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**My view:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LoginPage";
}
@model LayoutProject.Models.Login

<h2>LoginPage</h2>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<form action="/Home/Connection" method="post">
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(l=>l.Username)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(l=>l.Username)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Username")
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(l=>l.Password)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(l=>l.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Password")
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="createBook" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

**My model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LayoutProject.Models
{
    public class Login
    {
        [Required]
        public String Username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I submit my form, it will go in the controller, through the if statement but in my view it would display the default error message:The Username field is required.  Not the one that I pass.  Help please!

Comment: Because a `ModelState` error has already been added for the properties - the `ValidationMessage()` method will only display the first one (you can test this by calling `ModelState.Clear()` before adding your errors)

Comment: Buts whats wrong with just using `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez entrer un nom utilisateur")]` or using a resource file?

Comment: Yep I found this while debugging.  However, I don't know how to call the 2nd error properties.  Your solution works, but is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  I am actually learning asp.net and I am trying the different ways to display error messages.

Comment: BUt why would you do it this way? - which means if the user enter a value for `UserName` but leaves `Password` blank, you display an error message that the "Please enter a user name" which makes no sense because the user has entered it!. Just use `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez entrer un nom utilisateur")]`. And if you have client side validation, it will display the message and prevent submitting any way

Comment: In that case, I add two different conditions and ModelState.Clear() before the 2 conditions.  Still, I am just trying out different ways of doing it, even if it's not the best one.

Answer (score 0):

For showing model State Error on your view page you need to configure `ValidationSummary`.
You can do something like this in your view.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "youkey like username or whatever", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Please pass `false` parameter  in `Html.ValidationSummary`. After that you can see you model state error.